# Is there a way to convert string of certain format to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a string with a format like below:

```
string_1 = '{!Cat1!:{!A!:!xd!# !B!:!yd!# !C!:!zd!# !D!:[!nd!#!nd2!#!nd3!#!nd4!]# !E!:!hd!}#!Cat2!:{!A1!:!xd1!# !B1!:!yd1!# !C1!:!zd1!# !D1!:[!nd1!#!nd21!#!nd31!#!nd41!]# !E1!:!hd1!}}'
```

I wanted to check if there is a way to convert above string to below dataframe:

```
string_1_to_df
 
Col1 Col2 Col3

Cat1  A    xd
Cat1  B    yd
Cat1  C    zd
Cat1  D    nd
Cat1  D    nd2
Cat1  D    nd3
Cat1  D    nd4
Cat1  E    hd
Cat2  A1   xd1
Cat2  B1   yd1
Cat2  C1   zd1
Cat2  D1   nd1
Cat2  D1   nd21
Cat2  D1   nd31
Cat2  D1   nd41
Cat2  E1   hd1
```

I have tried with codes

```
new_String = string_1 .replace('!', '"').replace('#', ',')
new_String = json.loads(new_String )
new_String_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_String)
```

But the output I am getting is different and not in a dataframe

Comment: Of course there is.  It's simple string parsing.  What have you tried?  That LOOKS like JSON that has been munged.  If you `.replace('!','"').replace('#',',')`, then you can use `json.loads`.

Comment: this looks like a CS101 homework,  what have you tried?

Comment: I am new to python. And I am not sure how to do this. Need help?

Comment: If you replace the `!` with `"` and the `#` with `,` it turns into valid Python code for a dictionary, or JSON. Is that just a coincidence, or is it something you can rely on? And what have you already tried yourself, and where are you stuck? Check out [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I suggest you use a regular expression to extract the valid string because it is the more robust approach instead of using replace

Comment: @DejeneT. This isn't a regular language since it has nested brackets, so regex is probably not a great tool for the job.

Comment: So we can frame the answer in the right context, is this homework? If so, can you share any attempt you've made? I'm assuming it is given the obvious-to-most-of-us pattern of this string, otherwise the dev that decided to format their data in this matter should probably consider getting their work peer reviewed next time.

Comment: I have tried as suggested by guys :) and made an attempt. But unable to get the required dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the update with your code. You are on the right path! Now you just need to flatten this json/python-object into relational.

Comment: See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: @JNevill I edited my code and made an attempt:) But not able to get required output

Comment: @DejeneT. OP gets a notification for new answers, so there's no need to post a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step after you get your python object out of `json.loads` is to flatten your nested data. There are plenty of ways to do this, but being that you are likely not using advanced methods of pandas, dataframes, and even regular old python types, iterating through your object is probably the right level for your homework.

You'll likely need to nest a few `for` loops. As an example, to extract the first two columns of your dataframe from this nested output:

```
#your existing code
new_String = string_1 .replace('!', '"').replace('#', ',')
new_String = json.loads(new_String)

#iterating through the object to make a list of lists:
flattened = []
for col1 in new_String:
    for col2 in new_String[col1]:
        flattened.append([col1, col2])
```

To get that third element, you can iterate once again on `js[col1][col2]`. Note that there is an added level of complexity at this layer as you have elements like `'A':'xd'` as well as `'D': ['nd', 'nd2', 'nd3', 'nd4']` so you'll need to determine if you are working with a dictionary value of type `str` or `list` and iterate appropriately.

Once done you can push into a dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(flattened, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Process in 2 phases: 1) string parsing, 2) dataframe construction:

```
import json

d = json.loads(string_1.replace('!', '"').replace('#', ','))
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).stack().explode().reset_index()
     .pipe(lambda df: df.set_axis(range(df.shape[1]), axis=1)))
```

---

```
     0     1     2
0    A  Cat1    xd
1    B  Cat1    yd
2    C  Cat1    zd
3    D  Cat1    nd
4    D  Cat1   nd2
5    D  Cat1   nd3
6    D  Cat1   nd4
7    E  Cat1    hd
8   A1  Cat2   xd1
9   B1  Cat2   yd1
10  C1  Cat2   zd1
11  D1  Cat2   nd1
12  D1  Cat2  nd21
13  D1  Cat2  nd31
14  D1  Cat2  nd41
15  E1  Cat2   hd1
```

Comment: THANKS. But i see error ````'Series' object has no attriute 'explode'````

Comment: @naveepp, update your pandas, perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is considered bad practice to use `eval()` in your code. But nevertheless here is a solution using it:

```
import pandas as pd

string_1 = '{!Cat1!:{!A!:!xd!# !B!:!yd!# !C!:!zd!# !D!:[!nd!#!nd2!#!nd3!#!nd4!]# !E!:!hd!}#!Cat2!:{!A1!:!xd1!# !B1!:!yd1!# !C1!:!zd1!# !D1!:[!nd1!#!nd21!#!nd31!#!nd41!]# !E1!:!hd1!}}'

d = eval(string_1.replace("!", "'").replace("#", ','))
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df = {col: [] for col in cols}
for k, v in d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        if isinstance(v2, list):
            for j in v2:
                for col, v in zip(cols, [k, k2, j]):
                    df[col].append(v)
        else:
            for col, v in zip(cols, [k, k2, v2]):
                df[col].append(v)
                
string_to_df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(string_to_df)
```

Output:

```
    Col1 Col2  Col3
0   Cat1    A    xd
1   Cat1    B    yd
2   Cat1    C    zd
3   Cat1    D    nd
4   Cat1    D   nd2
5   Cat1    D   nd3
6   Cat1    D   nd4
7   Cat1    E    hd
8   Cat2   A1   xd1
9   Cat2   B1   yd1
10  Cat2   C1   zd1
11  Cat2   D1   nd1
12  Cat2   D1  nd21
13  Cat2   D1  nd31
14  Cat2   D1  nd41
15  Cat2   E1   hd1
```

Ideally, you would use regex instead, so I'll figure that out and update this post soon.